# Travelling with a damaged passport but scanner can still read it?

Tags: passports, international-travel, airports, israel

My passport has been damaged by water, (some water marks especially on page where you can see which country I visited) but I went to the French Embassy and the scanner can still read it.

Do you think it's OK to travel with it ? I'm going to Israel with ф stop in Dubai.

Comment: Are you talking about some smudges or your passport got soaked in water and the watermarks on the passport itself are damaged? It's hard to tell without seeing, to be safe better to get a new one.

Comment: Is it a French passport?  Did the French embassy make any comments about the water marks?

Comment: Last I went to Israel, they looked askance at passports with any sort of stamp from an Arab nation. That was in the 80s, and I don't know if things have changed, but you might want to travel by another country.

Comment: @FreeMan UAE has relationships with Israel and tons of Israelis are routinely vacationing there. Things have changed since the 80s.

Comment: Fair enough, @littleadv. Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: This happened to someone I know, was a water damaged Israeli Passport... they went through an additional check and then let the person through

Answer (score 1):

Because the passport is still machine-readable, it's likely OK.

But there's always the possibility that you will encounter an aggressive immigration official, who might object because some other part of the passport is obscured. This could include an entry or exit stamp, or a visa stamp or sticker, where the underlying text is difficult or impossible to read.

Your description of the issue as "water marks" suggests the issue is minor, but no one can guarantee it. Attaching a picture of the damage into your question would give us more to work with; use the "Edit" button, then select the "Moon and Mountains" toggle above the composition field. Make sure to obscure all personal information from the image before adding it to your question.